# Read CSV column, if requirements met, write to a cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am trying to read the first column of a CSV file and see if it meets requirements. If it meets the requirements, I want to write it to one of the following column.

As you can see from my code, i have the reading working (although not sure if the best method) I just need to get it to write to the 3 column in that row.

**Example**:
If any row in the first column contains a 4 digit value that starts with 25, enter a Y into the 3 column of that row.

**CSV Example:**

```
number,na,prefix25,na,na,na
1000,,,,,
1254,,,,,
251,,,,,
2501,,,,,
6548,,,,,
1478,,,,,
02,,,,,
2550,,,,,
2569,,,,,
```

**Desired CSV output:**

```
number,na,prefix25,na,na,na
1000,,,,,
1254,,,,,
251,,,,,
2501,,y,,,
6548,,,,,
1478,,,,,
02,,,,,
2550,,y,,,
2569,,y,,,
```

**Code so far:**

```
def micro():
    #Prefix 25
    with open(dbPath) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
        for i in reader:
            if len(i[0]) == 4:
                curStore = i[0].startswith("25")
                if curStore is True:
                    #Prints found numbers what are 4 digits and start with 25
                    print(i[0])
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with `pandas` using [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html). [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) method is more efficient than [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) as it is meant to be used for **column** wise operations, whereas [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) can be used for both **columns** and **the dataframe** :

```
import pandas as pd

#reading the csv as a dataframe  
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', delimiter=',')

#applying a lambda function using map
df['prefix25'] = df['number'].map(lambda x: 'y' if (str(x).startswith('25') and len(str(x))==4)  else '')

#replacing `NaN` with '' to match your requirements 
df.fillna('',inplace=True) 

#matching the columns as pandas automatically renames same columns 
df.columns = ['number','na','prefix25','na','na','na']

#saving the output csv
df.to_csv('output.csv',index=False)
```

**Output**:

```
number,na,prefix25,na,na,na
1000,,,,,
1254,,,,,
251,,,,,
2501,,y,,,
6548,,,,,
1478,,,,,
2,,,,,
2550,,y,,,
2569,,y,,,
```

Comment: This worked well. Only requirement it was missing, and i am unsure how to add to your method is, it needs to have 4 digits and prefixed with 25.

Comment: you mean something like `2550y` instead of `y`. Can you give an example?

Comment: Sure. From you above output, the line 251 should NOT have a y, because it does not have 4 digits. However 2501 SHOULD have a y because its 4 digits and starts with 25.

Comment: Okay. Added a quick fix. Can you check if it works for you?

Comment: Worked perfect!

Answer (score 3):

`pandas` are made for this task.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(<path_to_file>)
df['prefix25'] = df['number'].apply(lambda x: 'y' if str(x).startswith('25') else None)
df.to_csv(<path_and_file_name>)
```

Comment: So this seemed to work, however the updated CSV had a column added. example: 0,40,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: `df.to_csv(<path_and_file_name>, index=False)`

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach using a `temp` file

```
import csv
import os

def micro():
    #Prefix 25
    with open(dbPath) as f, open("temp_file", "w") as temp_outfile:  #Please provide full path to temp file
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
        writer = csv.writer(temp_outfile, delimiter="\t")
        for i in reader:
            if len(i[0]) == 4 and i[0].startswith("25"):
                i[2] = "Y"
            writer.writerow(i)
            
            #Replace Old File with TempFile
            os.rename("temp_file", dbPath)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following easy to understand steps:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('sofile.csv',',')
numlist = df.number.astype(str)
outlist = ['y' if (len(x)==4 and x.startswith('25')) else ''
            for x in numlist ]
df.prefix25 = outlist
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   number  na prefix25  na.1  na.2  na.3
0    1000 nan            nan   nan   nan
1    1254 nan            nan   nan   nan
2     251 nan            nan   nan   nan
3    2501 nan        y   nan   nan   nan
4    6548 nan            nan   nan   nan
5    1478 nan            nan   nan   nan
6       2 nan            nan   nan   nan
7    2550 nan        y   nan   nan   nan
8    2569 nan        y   nan   nan   nan
```

Can be saved back to csv using `df.to_csv('newfile.csv')` function.